# Can't align the image to the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a navbar that is 10vh high, and a banner that is 90vh high. I also have an image in the banner box. I wanted to align the image to the bottom of the screen so I gave the image the position: absolute and bottom: 0 parameters but it didn't work because it only aligned the image to the bottom of the viewport. And when I start scrolling down the image is not at the bottom of the banner.

HTML:

```
<nav></nav>
<div class="banner">
    <img src="./Polygon 2.png" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
}
*{
padding: 0%;
margin: 0%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
width: 100%; 
height: 10vh;
background-color: blueviolet;
}
.banner{
width: 100%;
height: 90vh;
background-color: chocolate;
overflow: hidden;
}
.banner img{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 30vh;
bottom: 0;
}
```

If you open this link on mobile you will see the problem:
https://elated-swirles-76c2d5.netlify.app

Comment: give your image to us so we can try it.

Comment: also what is you problem? is the black color box going up when we scroll the page?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: relative;` to `.banner`.

Without relative being on the parent, absolute positions itself based on the closest ancestor that is relative. If there is none, it goes to the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner{
width: 100%;
height: 90vh;
background-color: chocolate;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;

}
.banner img{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 30vh;
bottom: 0;
}
```

do it